# How do I prevent overfetching with graphQL

Tags: graphql, graphql-java, typegraphql

I am working with a project that uses graphQL. I understand that graphQL apis are supposed to prevent overfetching (and underfetching) of data but I do not understand how this is supposed to work in real life.

Say I have a query to get employee data like this:

```
const getEmployeesQuery = `
    query GetEmployees($aliases: [String]) {
        getEmployees(aliases: $aliases) {
            personId
            username
            fullName
            businessTitle
            email
            trainings
            location {
                id
                name
                buildingCode
                timezone
                city
                country
            } 
        }
    }
`;

export default getEmployeesQuery;
```

When this query is executed, our backend will get all this data from a variety of sources. However suppose that the request does not include `trainings` in the request. What I don't understand is how can the backed identify that this field is not there and then NOT make the operations to get that data?

Is the graphQL backend supposed to parse through this string to determine what the user requested at every level? That seems unrealistic.

Ideally if I don't include `trainings` (or any particular field) then the backend should be optimized to not retrieve that data, right? The query I posted here is relatively simple but we have some that are extremely nested.
The frontend will only end up receiving data included in the request but shouldn't we be preventing the backend from getting data not included in the request body? That is what I don't understand.

Comment: Yes, this is how GraphQL works. If you don't ask for a field the backend won't go fetch it. GraphQL does in fact parse through the request and figure out what *resolvers* need to be called based on what is being requested. Deep nesting doesn't matter.

Comment: @MichelFloyd thanks for the response. However in my backend I am writing the code that receives a request and calls the correct resolvers It seems like I'd need to check the data at every level of the request to see if I need to get that particular object. Is there a library or something that does this automatically?

Comment: In your example you'd have a *query* resolver for `GetEmployees`. Your `Employee` type would then have other resolvers for various fields, ex: `location`. Your `location` resolver will not get called if you don't ask for it in your query results. That is automatic with a GraphQL server such as [Apollo-Server](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/)

Answer (score 0):

**You're correct**; one of the main benefits of `GraphQL` is that it doesn't over-fetch.

From `client` to `server`, this is easy to prevent. Request the fields you want, and the `client` will receive them from the `server`. So just remove `trainings` from your Client-side request. However, that doesn't prevent `GraphQL` from hitting your `database` for every field in your request, including `trainings`.

What you need is to pass the `info` data at the `Resolver` level. I am currently using `Nestjs` with `GraphQL` & `knex` so my implementation looks like this:

Focus on `Info`

```js
import { Args, Info, Query, Resolver } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { UsersService } from './users.service';
import { User } from 'src/common/models/user.model';
import { UsersArgs } from 'src/users/arguments/users.args';
import { Role, Roles } from 'src/auth/auth.role.decorator';

@Resolver(() => User)
export class UsersResolver {
  constructor(private readonly usersService: UsersService) {}

  @Query(() => [User])
  @Roles(Role.Inner)
  async users(@Args() getUsersDataArgs: UsersArgs, @Info() info: any): Promise<User[]> {
    const requestedFields = this.extractRequestedFields(info);

    return this.usersService.find(getUsersDataArgs, requestedFields);
  }

  private extractRequestedFields(info: any): string[] {
    const selections = info.fieldNodes[0].selectionSet.selections;
    return selections.map((selection: any) => selection.name.value);
  }
}
```

You'll now have access to the requested fields in your service and can now use them something like this:

```js
const selectRequest = /* use requestedFields to create dynamic select query here */
const query = this.knex
        .select(selectRequest)
        .from('foo')
        .where('bar', bar)
```

## Hope this helps!